# Add event listeners to multiple dynamic elements in a closure with jquery.on function without multiple elements firing after single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, onclicklistener

I am trying to add a click event listener to the dynamically created li's so that they work independent of each other(currently, all three fire when you click one of them). Every solution I see involves a closure which I thought I was doing but i guess not. Also, the view keeps getting updated with last element in the model array and I can't figure out why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Data displayed in the view
  var model = {
    carOnDisplay: null,
    listOfCars: [{
        numClicks: 0,
        carName: "Challenger",
        color: 'grey'
      },
      {
        numClicks: 0,
        carName: "Charger",
        color: 'blue'
      },
      {
        numClicks: 0,
        carName: "Mustang",
        color: 'orange'
      },
    ]
  };

  var controller = {

    init: function() {
      // set the default car to be displayed
      model.carOnDisplay = model.listOfCars[0];
      carView.init();
      carListView.init();
    },

    getListOfCars: function() {
      return model.listOfCars;
    },

    setCurrentCar: function(car) {
      model.carOnDisplay = car;
    },

    getCurrentCar: function() {
      return model.carOnDisplay;
    },

    incrementClicks: function() {

      model.carOnDisplay.numClicks++;
      carView.render();

    }
  };

  var carView = {
    init: function() {
      // cached DOM
      this.car = $('#car');
      this.name = $('h3.carName');
      this.clicks = $('h4.clicks');
      // add click listeners to car
      this.car.click(function() {
        controller.incrementClicks();
      });
      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      var currentCar = controller.getCurrentCar();
      this.car.css('background-color', currentCar.color);
      this.name.html(currentCar.carName);
      this.clicks.html(currentCar.numClicks);
    }
  };

  var carListView = {
    init: function() {
      // cache DOM elements
      this.carList = $('#carList');
      this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
      //  this.links = $('#carList').getElementsByTagName('li');
      var car = controller.getListOfCars(),
        currentCar = controller.getCurrentCar();




      for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
        var carNow = car[i];

        $('#carList').append("<li>" + carNow.carName + "</li>");
        $('#carList').on('click', one());

        //     // controller.setCurrentCar(carNow);
        //     // carView.render();

      };

      function one() {
        return function(event) {
          controller.setCurrentCar(carNow);
          carView.render();
        }
      }
    }
  } // end of carListView
  controller.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <ul id="carList">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="col-9">
    <div id="car" class="col-4">
      <h3 class="carName">x</h3>
      <h4 class="clicks"></h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This looks so hugely complicated compared to one single `$('#carList').on('click', "li",one);`

Comment: Your end goal is completely unclear, that said, if you can explain what you actual want to do, Im certain we can help you do it much simpler.

Comment: @DelightedD0D thanks for your reply and i apologize for my terrible description...I am not very good with the lingo yet. Anywhoo...my code creates an ul of li's which also have event listeners binded to them when created. There are 2 problems so far. #1. If i click on one of the li's, the event handlers for tall the others fires too(only the one clicked should fire), #2. no matter which li i click, the carView is always updated with last car in model array.

Comment: So use delegation as I showed you. I cannot see a reason to bind an event handler to each LI when using jQuery

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mplungjan, i am currently learning the mvc design pattern to reduce my tendancy to write spaghetti code.

Comment: For one thing, you're calling `$('#carList').on('click', one);` that's binding a handler to the `#carList` element and calling `one()` every time a user clicks anywhere in it, including when you click on one of it's children. Like mplungjan said, use `$('#carList').on('click', "li",one);` to bind to it but listen for clicks on the individual `li`s inside '#carList'. But more to the point, that whole thing looks kinda overcomplicated. You're still explaining what you're *trying to do* NOT the *goal you're trying to achieve*. What should this whole thing do? Also, the html would help.

Comment: Well - in this case you MVCd yourself into a corner. I don't even want to try and untangle your code ;) Also I think this is an X/Y problem

Comment: @mplungjan I have done as you suggested and used $('#carList').on('click', "li", one()); but im still having the same issue which is that all the li's fire when only one is clicked.

Comment: @DelightedD0D the goal of the whole thing is to dynamically create li's that update the car view with car info stored in the clicked dynamic LI..about to post the HTML now

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Remember to only delegate once: `$(document).ready(function() { $("#carList").on("click","li",one); ...`

Comment: @mplungjan you were right about single delegation, i moved the above mentioed code out of the loop and into the global space and now each LI is firing one time only...now the only problem is that they all fire with data from the last car object in the model.car array.

Comment: `function one() {
           controller.setCurrentCar($(this));
          carView.render();
        }
      }`

Comment: @mplungjan the "this" keyword causes the li not to fire at all..

Comment: You need to use the jQuery object passed - I am not going to rewrite your entire code for you since I do not like your abstraction anyway

Comment: @mplunigan..you've been a life saver! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm a newbie and help from pros like yourself is invaluable to my progression.